# How to create an instance of unittest test class?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to create an instance of unittest TestCase so that i can use the variables and methods of that class, but it's throwing me an error:

```
In [1]: import tests

In [2]: obj = tests.TestDailyAggregations()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6a5e2091c8a1> in <module>()
----> 1 obj = tests.TestDailyAggregations()

/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py in __init__(self, methodName)
    187         except AttributeError:
    188             raise ValueError("no such test method in %s: %s" %
--> 189                   (self.__class__, methodName))
    190         self._testMethodDoc = testMethod.__doc__
    191         self._cleanups = []

ValueError: no such test method in <class 'tests.TestDailyAggregations'>: runTest
```

Following is my tests.py file in which i want to make an instance of TestDailyAggregations and use it's variable user_daily_dict in TestWeeklyAggregations:

```
import unittest
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rest_apis.settings")


    class TestDailyAggregations(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_daily_aggregation(self):

            ......

            daily = daily_aggregations
            user_daily_dict = daily.generate_aggregations_dictionary(user_workouts)

            date_list = self.get_dates(user_daily_dict)
            unique = self.check_unique_date(date_list)
            self.assertEqual(unique, True)

            total = self.check_total(user_daily_dict, user_workouts)
            self.assertEqual(total, True)

        def generate_mock_workouts(self, start_time, end_time):
            f......

        def get_dates(self, user_daily_dict):
            ......

        def check_unique_date(self, date_list):
            ......

        def check_total(self, user_daily_dict, user_workouts):
            ......

        def check_sum(self, user_daily_dict, user_workouts, calculate):
            ......

    class TestWeeklyAggregations(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_weekly_aggregations(self):
            obj = TestDailyAggregations
            user_daily_dict = obj.test_daily_aggregation(obj).user_daily_dict

            w = weekly_aggregations
            user_weekly_dict = w.generate_aggregations_dictionary(user_daily_dict)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.TextTestRunner().run(TestDailyAggregations())
```

What should I do to make instance?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to instance it by passing it a methodName it contains (`setUp` for instance). Here is the code of `TestCase` class, as you see :

```
def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
    """Create an instance of the class that will use the named test
       method when executed. Raises a ValueError if the instance does
       not have a method with the specified name.
    """
```

After instantiating it, you can access the methods it contains. 
(I often debug my unittest with this trick...)